# Why I can't read Exif Data and rotate image?

Tags: php, exif

I'm trying to make upload image rotation. But I can' read Exif data from image and my rotating not working. I have tried a lot of solutions that I have found on internet but nothing works. Can someone help me with this?

This is my code:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['rotate']))
{
    $filename = $_FILES['image']['name'];
    $tmp_name = $_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"];
    $location = 'image/';

    echo $exif = exif_read_data($tmp_name); // <----- Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\novo\index.php on line 20

    if (!empty($exif['Orientation'])) {
        $source = imagecreatefromjpeg($tmp_name);
        switch ($exif['Orientation']) {
            case 3:
                $image = imagerotate($source, 180, 0);
                break;
            case 6:
                $image = imagerotate($source, -90, 0);
                break;
            case 8:
                $image = imagerotate($source, 90, 0);
                break;
            default:
                $image = $source;
        } 
        $rotatedImage = imagejpeg($image, $filename, 90);
        move_uploaded_file($tmp_name,$location.$rotatedImage);

        echo "Success";
    }
}
?>

<html>
<body>
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="image" />
<input type="submit" name="rotate" value="rotate" />

</form>


<table>
<tr><td>UploadImage</td>
<td height="500px" width="500px" align="center">
<img src="image/<?php echo $image; ?>" width="300px" height="300px" />

</td>
<td>RotateImage</td>
<td headers="500px" width="500px" align="center"><img src="rotated/<?php echo $image; ?>" width="300px" height="300px" /></td></tr>
</table>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the output of your script ? You are trying to echo $exif but it is an array. What does a var_dump($exif) output ?
Are you sure your exif data contain an Orientation information ?

Comment: This is var_dump information:  array(7) { ["FileName"]=> string(11) "phpAC75.tmp" ["FileDateTime"]=> int(1573135650) ["FileSize"]=> int(86149) ["FileType"]=> int(2) ["MimeType"]=> string(10) "image/jpeg" ["SectionsFound"]=> string(0) "" ["COMPUTED"]=> array(4) { ["html"]=> string(25) "width="960" height="1280"" ["Height"]=> int(1280) ["Width"]=> int(960) ["IsColor"]=> int(1) } }

Comment: As you can see, there is no Orientation exif data

Comment: So, is there some other way to make upload images on correct rotation?

Comment: I can't see how, you have no way do know which rotation is the correct one

Comment: This has nothing to do with EXIF. You are trying to `echo` an array. You need to read the documentation/your book.

Comment: Also, if the information doesn't contain Orientation, then the information doesn't contain Orientation. You need to take that up with whoever provides the file. What can we do about that?